# Which function in the Linux kernel creates the segments?

Tags: linux-kernel, tcp

I'm working on a problem for my Master's degree and I'm trying to track down how a segment is created and how it calculates the checksum. I've located a function called `tcp_sendmsg()` but, even by its name, it sounds like it does far more than just build a segment. I'm probably being naïve, but I'm assuming its a general function that takes in the source and destination ports, a list of flags and a pointer to the data and returns a segment. Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

By segment I mean the Protocol Data Unit that is created by the Transport Layer (not the packet that's created by the Network Layer nor the frame that's created by the Data Link layer.)

Specifically, I mean the segment that looks like this (a screengrab of one of my Wireshark sessions):

[image]

Comment: um, "segment": that word means different things in different contexts. What "segment" are you referring to, *exactly*?

Comment: There are a few places where TCP segments may be created, including `tcp_sendmsg()`, but IIRC `tcp_stream_alloc_skb()` is used to allocate them (see https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/tcp_stream_alloc_skb). You'll be interested in the `struct sk_buff` structure which holds packet contents along with all of the headers (see http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb.html).